# Can we force a function to repaint?

Tags: pine-script

I created this function to get the timestamp of given bar offset.

```
// on the 1mn timeframe
getBarTime(lookbehind) => 
    timestamp(year(timenow), month(timenow), dayofmonth(timenow), hour(timenow), minute(timenow), 0) - lookbehind*60*1000
```

it seems to work as expected, however it seems like it is not repainting when I plot:

```
plot(time == getBarTime(2) ? 1 : 0)
```

it freezes the output timestamp and never repaints.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the opening time at any given offset using `time[offset]`.

This allows to see what's going on in the realtime bar:

```
//@version=4
study("")
// on the 1mn timeframe
getBarTime(lookbehind) => 
    timestamp(year(timenow), month(timenow), dayofmonth(timenow), hour(timenow), minute(timenow), 0) - lookbehind*60*1000
// Condition is only true once, when the script executes on the second to last bar of the dataset.
bgcolor(time == getBarTime(2) ? color.green : na)
plot(getBarTime(2))
// Get time 2 bars back.
plotchar(time[2], "time[2]", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
// See `timenow` advance on each realtime bar iteration (has a 1sec precision).
plotchar(timenow, "timenow", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
```

On historical bars, `timenow` will update every second, so the change will only be visible if your script takes >1sec to execute on them.

Comment: Thanks but I may not clearly understand why my function is true only once. Isn't `timenow` supposed to repaint every second?! For instance, the last plot() of your answer repaints at every new candle. Shouldn't my function do that too since it is based on `timenow` as well ??

Comment: Ok I think I got it. My function is evaluated once at script execution. So it takes `timenow` at time of exec, and that's it. Then my question is still on the table I guess: Is there a way to get the expected result but repainting at each candle? `time[2]` is the timestamp of ante-last offset AT EACH CURRENT CANDLE. It is true at all candles except the first two. What my function tries to get is the timestamp of the ante-last candle NOW. And now. And now. Etc... forever. Always based on `timenow`.

Comment: Yes, that's correct: if your script takes less than 1 second to execute on the dataset, `timenow` will not change during the execution of the script on historical bars. It will only start updating in the realtime bar, at every price/volume update, with a 1sec precision. If you want the time 2 bars back, and only when your script is executing on the dataset's most recent bar, you could use `t = barstate.islast ? time[2] : na`.